# Invalid operands to binary expression error...when creating ratio

Tags: c, debugging

```
double profit_ratio = ((double) definitive_seller_profit) / ((double)definitive_buyer_profit); 

        if(definitive_buyer_profit > definitive_seller_profit){

            if(definitive_buyer_move < 0 && definitive_seller_move < 0 && profit_ratio >= 0.50){ // give seller a chance if it's on the way and at least 50% profit ratio

                if((definitive_buyer_move < definitive_seller_move)){
                    *n = to_fuel_or_not_to_fuel(b, definitive_seller_move, fuel_ratio);
                } else {
                    *n = to_fuel_or_not_to_fuel(b, definitive_buyer_move, fuel_ratio); 
                }
            }

            } else if(definitive_buyer_move > 0 && definitive_seller_move > 0 &&  && profit_ratio >= 0.50){

                if(definitive_buyer_move > definitive_seller_move){

                    *n = to_fuel_or_not_to_fuel(b, definitive_seller_move, fuel_ratio);
                } 
                else {
                    *n = to_fuel_or_not_to_fuel(b, definitive_buyer_move, fuel_ratio); 
                }

            } else{

                *n = to_fuel_or_not_to_fuel(b, definitive_buyer_move, fuel_ratio);

            }

        }
```

So I'm getting invalid operands to binary expression ('void*'and 'double') in line:

else if(definitive_buyer_move > 0 && definitive_seller_move > 0 &&  && profit_ratio >= 0.50)

And I'm also getting...undeclared label 'profit_ratio.'

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question. It is hard to reproduce your problem in the current form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&&  &&` has no meaning in:

```
else if(definitive_buyer_move > 0 && definitive_seller_move > 0 &&  && profit_ratio >= 0.50){
```

hence the *invalid operands*.

For the *undeclared label*, fixing the previous error might solve the issue or

- `definitive_buyer_profit` does not exist;
- `definitive_seller_profit` does not exist;
- `definitive_buyer_profit` has a type that has no casting to `double`;
- `definitive_seller_profit` has a type that has no casting to `double`

Anyway, your entire provided code is a bunch of `if`-`else if`-`else` for calling the same function in all cases. In this situation, consider using another (more readable, IMO) approach *e.g.*

```
if (b_profit > s_profit)
{
    const bool both_move_neg = b_move < 0 && s_move < 0;
    const bool both_move_pos = b_move > 0 && s_move > 0;
    const bool high_ratio = 2*abs(s_profit) >= abs(b_profit);
    const bool pick_s = ((both_move_neg && b_move < s_move) ||
                         (both_move_pos && s_move < b_move)) && high_ratio;

    *n = to_fuel_or_not_to_fuel(b, pick_s ? s_move : b_move, fuel_ratio); 
}
```

requiring (notice that this is C99 code)

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
```

where I renamed your variable to more convenient names (`to_fuel_or_not_to_fuel` could undergo the same treatment; maybe `fuel` or `conditional_fuel`?) and I assumed `s_profit` and `b_profit` to be `int`s.

---

After having tried to edit your post, I realized how messy your code was! Not only are my previous remarks (about naming and using more readable conditions) still true but you **must** work on you indentation (and brackets)!

See by yourself: By indenting your code "properly" based on what you provide, I get

```
double profit_ratio = ((double) definitive_seller_profit) / ((double) definitive_buyer_profit); 

if (definitive_buyer_profit > definitive_seller_profit){
    if (definitive_buyer_move < 0 && definitive_seller_move < 0 && profit_ratio >= 0.50){
        // give seller a chance if it's on the way and at least 50% profit ratio
        if (definitive_buyer_move < definitive_seller_move){
            *n = to_fuel_or_not_to_fuel(b, definitive_seller_move, fuel_ratio);
        } else {
            *n = to_fuel_or_not_to_fuel(b, definitive_buyer_move, fuel_ratio); 
        }
    }
} else if (definitive_buyer_move > 0 && definitive_seller_move > 0 &&  && profit_ratio >= 0.50){
    if (definitive_buyer_move > definitive_seller_move){
        *n = to_fuel_or_not_to_fuel(b, definitive_seller_move, fuel_ratio);
    } else {
        *n = to_fuel_or_not_to_fuel(b, definitive_buyer_move, fuel_ratio); 
    }
} else {
    *n = to_fuel_or_not_to_fuel(b, definitive_buyer_move, fuel_ratio);
}
}
```

Notice two things:

1. The `if { if {...} else if {...} else {...} }` that your indentation is implying is **not** what your wrote (remember that space characters have no meaning in C and are ignored);
2. The last `}` has no corresponding `{`.

The last point makes me think that the *undeclared label* errors comes from the fact that when you are using the variable in the conditions (`else`) `if (/*...*/ profit_ratio >= 0)` your terrible indentation lead to mismatching brackets which themselves lead to the definition of `profit_ratio` being trapped in another block of code, leading to it being undefined where it is used.

Finally, notice that the error about `profit_ratio` might actually come (as I implied) from the conditions and not from its definition (with the ratio). Therefore, it would have been more effective for you to include the line at which the error was detected.

So, in conclusion, you should:

1. Write readable code;
2. Understand what you compiler says;
3. Write readable questions;
4. Add the relevant information to these questions.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :-
`} else if(definitive_buyer_move > 0 && definitive_seller_move > 0 &&  && profit_ratio >= 0.50){`
to
`} else if(definitive_buyer_move > 0 && definitive_seller_move > 0 && profit_ratio >= 0.50){`
You have 2 `&& &&` s
Also consider parenthesizing your logic for better readability:-
`} else if((definitive_buyer_move > 0) && (definitive_seller_move > 0) && ( profit_ratio >= 0.50)){`